# Delta Sigma Modulator for 2/3 Multi modulus divider used in FracN PLL

Tags: modulation, pll, sampling, synthesizer, frequency-synthesis

I have been trying to implement a Delta Sigma modulator for a 2/3 Multi Modulus divider. I am referring to Riley's paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=229400

I have designed the same 2nd order DSM as shown in this paper. I am simulating the design on cadence. However, I am not sure how to

1. Calculate the input bit stream for a particular fractional ratio. What values need to be fed into the DSM?
2. How do I see that in cadence simulation DSM is giving correct average value?

Attaching a block diagram for reference and Riley's paper is attached in the link.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the citation list to find the papers that refer to this one (*Delta-Sigma Modulation in Fractional-N Frequency Synthesis*)? They may be of some added help where the paper itself hasn't helped you. Just a thought.

Comment: You don't calculate the bitstream, the DSM does, from the fraction and modulus that you feed it. 2nd order should not be that complicated, add a block diagram (down to the adder level) for it to your question, so we know how to help you. To check the correct average value, average it. Most easily done by taking the spectrum via an FFT, as you'll want to see the spectrum anyway (that's what a DSM does, shape the spectrum!), and the average is 'just' the DC value of the transform. 'Just' as there are a few normalising things to get right before the FFT spits out the correct average.

Comment: I have added the paper and block diagram. I have made a 12 bit DSM. I want to know what goes inside the first accumulator such that a specific DC average value is set at the output. I also have one more doubt which is: How are the accumulators and quantizer clocked (in my case the accumulators are clocked by the output of multi modulus divider and the quantizer is clocked by ref frequency). Any reference or advice if you can share will be very helpful

Comment: @Neil_UK I've provided a quick link [here](http://www.infinitefactors.org/docs/1993,%20Riley,%20Delta-Sigma%20Modulation%20in%20Fractional-N%20Frequency%20Synthesis.pdf) that will provide access for a while. However, I will need to remove the link at some point in time. I don't think the paper is sufficiently helpful, though. But that's just me skimming. If you can make something useful from it, best wishes.

Comment: @PranjalMahajan I still can't get any of your links to work. Are they for the paper in IEEE JOURNAL OF SOLID-STATE CIRCUITS, VOL. 28, NO. 5. MAY 1993 Riley et al? If so, figures 5 and 9 are very useful. All accumulators are clocked by the same source. The fact that the reference frequency and the feedback from the divider are, when the PLL is locked, at the same frequency means either can be used (not both, please!), but there are practical issues to choose one or the other for safe start up when out of lock (it's a while since I did all this stuff, so hazy memory).

Comment: Thanks very much @Nei

Comment: Thanks very much @Neil_UK. I will certainly use this point in my design. Yes I am talking about Riley 1993 paper JSSC. Also if you can help me with the input value which goes into the first accumulator will be very helpful. Any book, paper, reference, link...anything will work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @periblepsis for supporting the answers

Comment: @PranjalMahajan Looking at the first accumulator in fig 5, it gets either K+M or K-M each clock cycle. M represents +/- 1, which is +/- the reference frequency. Therefore K/M is the fraction of the ref frequency generated (Or is it half that or twice that? You can find out when you simulate it). Keep abs(K/M) as <= 0.5 to maintain loop stability. M, the modulus, the denominator of the fraction, can be chosen arbitrarily. So if ref freq = 1 MHz, and M = 10^6, then you can generate 1 Hz steps, K = Hz.

Comment: @Neil_UK Once you pull down a copy of the paper (hopefully, already), I'll pull it off the site. Or if you no longer need it. Either way, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @periblepsis yeah, got it, thx

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for taking a moment for Pranjal. I've removed the link.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I will apply these comments and reply back here. Kindly keep checking

Comment: @PranjalMahajan I don't know Cadence. What I would strongly recommend is implementing Riley's figure 5 in an excel spreadsheet, or a simple programming language, like C, python, Matlab, whatever, just to see what it does, and to generate some test vectors that you can use to verify other implementations.